# creating Unix script to check for directories and subdirectories in

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I'm completing the following for one of my assignments using Korn shell.

For each argument in the argument list (which becomes the current pathname):

1. Check whether the current pathname is a directory, and if so:
2. Initialize a variable maxsubdir with the null (empty) string, and
   a  maxentries variable to 0;
3. For each entry in the directory check if that entry represents a
   directory and if so, find the numbers of entries in that
   subdirectory with a pipe consisting of `ls -l` and `wc`, and save the
   result in a variable named curentries.
4. Compare curentries with maxentries, and if curentries is greater,
   update maxsubdir and maxentries. (--10 points)
5. When the `for` cycle for a directory is completed, display (with
   echo) the directory name, maxsubdir and maxentries (with appropriate
   explanatory text.)
6. If the pathname in a) is not a directory, display the pathname
   and an explanatory text saying that  the pathname does not represent
   a directory.
7. Go to the next command line argument (pathname) and repeat 1-7

The execution of the script ends when all pathnames are processed (the `while` is completed )

***This is the code I have for it so far (EDITED):***

```
#!/bin/ksh

directoy=$1
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    if [ -d $1 ]; then
        maxsubdir=
        maxentries=0
        for x in $1; do
            echo "Checking if $1 represents a directory..\n"
            curentries="ls -l | wc"
            if [ $curentries > $maxentries ]; then
                maxentries=$curentries
                maxsubdir=$curentries
            fi; 
        done
        echo "The directory structure of $1 is … \n"
        echo "Maximum sub directories: \n"
        echo "$maxsubdir\n"
        echo "Maximum directory entries: \n"
        echo "$maxentries"
    fi
done
```

1. Where do I need to insert the "shift" command since I Unix can only handle a limited number of arguments?
2. Is my syntax appropriate? Or do I have syntax errors on sort lines?
3. Script seems to run but does not produce output to screen? Perhaps it's endless?

Comment: You need a space in the `if condition`. `if [ $curentries > $maxentries ]`

Comment: iamauser, ty, I added the spaces. Still cannot get spaced the 'error on line 6' complaint..

Comment: You use the $varname when getting the value of a variable. Get rid of the $ when you are assigning it

Comment: remove the "true" from your while loop -- the test command ("[") is doing the boolean evaluation

Comment: to retain the output of a command in a variable, you need to use parentheses or backticks: `curentries = \`ls -l | wc\``. Note also I removed the $

Comment: mpez0, TY. I added the corrections.

Comment: Go to http://www.shellcheck.net/ and paste your code there - while built for `sh` / `bash`, `ksh` is similar enough for the analysis to be useful; also: your shebang line is missing the initial `#`; please format _all_ of the source code in your question as such (indent with 4 spaces).

Comment: Note that you don't use the `directoy` variable.  You have an infinite loop because you never shift.  But you probably shouldn't be using a `while` loop anyway; `for name in "$@"` would be a better loop to use (where technically the `in "$@"` is optional, but personally I always write it for explicitness), not least because you don't have to worry about where to shift.

Comment: You ask about 'sort lines' but there are no lines with an explicit sort.  Your echo commands leave a blank line between the identification string and the number.  You should probably be using a single `echo` for each item, such as: `echo "Maximum directory entries: $maxentries"`.  In your script, the `shift` belongs before the final `done`.  You have a problem because you have `for x in $1` where you probably need `for x in $1/*`.

Comment: `[ $foo > $bar ]` is incorrect here. You're looking for `-gt`. `man [`:  
s1 < s2       True if string s1 comes before s2 based on the ASCII value of their characters.  
s1 > s2       True if string s1 comes after s2 based on the ASCII value of their characters.  
n1 -eq n2     True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal.  
n1 -gt n2     True if the integer n1 is algebraically greater than the integer n2.  
n1 -ge n2     True if the integer n1 is algebraically greater than or equal to the integer n2.  
n1 -lt n2     True if the integer n1 is algebraically less than the integer n2.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here and see if this helps out. Explanations are in the code.

```
#!/bin/ksh

    directory=$1

    # check whether the entered path is a directory
    if [ -d $1 ];then # yes, it's a directory
            maxsubdir=null
            maxentries=0
            echo "$1 is a directory"

            # you are only counting lines, add -l to wc
            # also you have to not count the first line. it's returns the size
            curentries=`ls -l $1 | wc -l`
            echo ${curentries}
    fi
```

Comment: Alex, I did that but still have "error on line 6." Ironically, 'then' is now located on line 5 along with the beginning of the IF-STATEMENT.

Comment: Do you have spaces in between the [ and your statement and ]?

Comment: I added if [ -d $1 ]; then to my LINE 5. Yes, I have the spaces. Not sure why the first error keeps happening though.

Comment: Alex, thank you. I improvised my code per what you wrote. I edited my initial question(s).

Comment: Note that `null` is not the empty string (and the question does explicitly identify 'the null (empty) string'

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't.
2. You do have some errors.
3. Or perhaps, it never reaches that code?

#### Your assignment says specifically to use a `for` loop, and you've implemented a `while` loop.

I'll get you started:

```
for directory in $*; do
  cd "$directory"
  curentries=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
  for entry in $(ls -1); do
    ...
  done
done
```

Comment: Also, "current pathname" is somewhat vague terminology, but if your instructor uses that to mean "current directory", you're being told to `cd` to each directory.